# how to read attribute from json

Tags: api, azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I want to read values of a json (message) object which has array in it.

This below query helps for immediate properties in d.

```
traces | extend d = parsejson(message) | d.Timestamp, d.Name;
```

How do I read property part of an array within  d (message). For example if I want to read all street values in below message .. how to do ? This is kind of needing a loop

```
message
{
    "Timestamp": "12-12-2008",
    Name: "Alex",
    address: {
        [{"street": "",zip:""},{"street":"", "zip":""}]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be using the `mvexpand` operator (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#mvexpand-operator)).
It will output a single row for each element in your array which you could iterate over.
So in your example, running:

```
traces | extend d = parsejson(message) | mvexpand d.address
```

Will output a row for each address.

Comment: Thanks @EranG , This works! For the sake of all here is a sample query:                                                                                                    'traces
| extend x = parsejson("{\"name\":\"sp1\", \"addresses\": [{\"street\":\"hollywood blvd\"},{\"street\":\"mullhond drive\"}] }").addresses
| mvexpand x
| project x;'